# JVM - Are WeakReferences collected in minor GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, weak-references

I was wondering about that since that would make them less useful. If so, is there a way to make memory weakly referenced only "garbage" on major GC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The javadoc does not specifically state what the "timescales" are for clearing / breaking `WeakReference`s.  That would make the answer to your question (at least in theory) "it is implementation dependent".  Indeed, the JLS spec and javadocs don't even mention major versus minor collections.  The whole topic comes is in the "implementation details" category.

If you do want references that are GC sensitive, then maybe you should use a [`SoftReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) instead.  That is described as follows:

> *"All soft references to softly-reachable objects are guaranteed to have been cleared before the virtual machine throws an OutOfMemoryError. Otherwise no constraints are placed upon the time at which a soft reference will be cleared or the order in which a set of such references to different objects will be cleared. Virtual machine implementations are, however, encouraged to bias against clearing recently-created or recently-used soft references."*

Elsewhere, a soft reference is described as stronger than a weak reference.  The implication is that it is less likely to be broken; e.g. by an over-eager garbage collector.  But note that none of this talks about major vs minor garbage collections.

---

**UPDATE** I researched the following (highly plausible!) claim in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16977182/139985 in the Java 11 source tree:

> Minor collections will collect any object in the young space. A `WeakReference`  to an object in the young space will be collected on a minor GC.

The native Reference handling code is complicated.  There is a general `ReferenceProcessor` class that does the following:

- It selectively records `Reference` objects that a GC encounters.  The GC code calls `ReferenceProcessor::discover_reference` to make this happen.
- It iterates the discovered `Reference` objects to determine whether or not to break the references.  The relevant `Reference` objects are added to their respective reference queues.

The complications are as follows:

- A GC may or may not call `ReferenceProcessor::discover_reference`.  From what I can tell, most (if not all) GCs do call it, but it is hard to be sure.
- The `ReferenceProcessor` has different policies for dealing with the case where the reference and referent are in different generations (or spans).  (If a reference is not going to processed, the referent will be treated as hard reachable for the current collection.)

In short, I can confirm that `Reference` objects will *typically* be processed in a minor GC.  However, the actual behavior a particular `Reference` *may* depend on generation / span issues.

<sup>(It should be possible to *observe* the general behavior for a particular GC from the GC logs.  Look for the stats or timings for reference processing phases.)</sup>

---

<sup>1 - The "span" term is used in comments.  I think it relates to collectors (e.g. G1) that break the old generation into a number of regions (spans) that are collected separately.</sup>

Comment: Friendly advise, never use SoftReference. In HotSpot JVM SoftReference are implemented in very strange way. JVM decides whenever to collect SoftReference or not by access timestamps (last time to have called get() Real garbage weight is not accounted.

Comment: @AlexeyRagozin - That sounds consistent with the javadoc.  And the javadoc doesn't say **anything** about *"garbage weight"*, so I don't understand why you would expect it to take that into account.  If you wanted the GC to break references to "big" objects in preference to "small" ones, you would need to implement that yourself (maybe using wrapped WeakReferences and reference queues ...)

Comment: @AlexeyRagozin - In short, I think your advice is not well-founded.

Comment: @AlexeyRagozin They can't take the garbage weight into account as they can't know it. Actually, there's no sane definition of this weight, given that parts of the object graph may be shared between multiple references. Moreover, many GCs are efficient because they don't touch garbage; they rescue the non-garbage instead and what's left is free memory.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want that?  Your program shouldn't care much about major vs minor GC cycles, and in fact that sort of differentiation won't even exist in all JVMs / GC configurations.

`WeakReference`s are collectable as soon as there are no strong references to the object.  This could include minor GCs.

If you want the object to stick around for a while until there is actual memory pressure, try [SoftReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) instead.

Comment: You can't deny it's a detail worth knowing. It makes a lot of difference for example while implementing a cache or something.

Comment: @PabloFernandez: I disagree.  If you rely on knowing implementation details for your cache, it's going to break when someone upgrades their JVM and it'll be a royal pain to debug why...

Comment: IMHO The difference between "collected as soon as possible"(WeakReferences) and "collected as late as possible" (SoftReferences) is worth knowing, valuable, and important when implementing anything that allocates memory that your app can live without (e.g caches)

Comment: That's totally different from the question you asked, at least as I read it.  WeakReference vs SoftReference is useful knowledge, I agree.

Comment: Unless done stupidly, it won't break, it'll just became less efficient (though the difference may be so huge it'll effectively kill the app). I could imagine that having a `NotSoWeakReference` collected only on major GC (and a `ReallyWeakReference` collected always) would be useful for caching.

Answer (score 3):

You may be thinking of SoftReferences which may be closer to what you want.

Minor collections will collect any object in the young space.  A WeakReference to an object in the young space will be collected on a minor GC.  A WeakReference to an object in the tenured space will be collected on tenured collection e.g. Full GC.  BTW You can have concurrent collections of only the tenured space.

Comment: +1 - Do you have a reference for this?  (Not that I doubt your word ...)

Answer (score 2):

It will depend if the WeakReference object is in Eden or not - a minor collection will only look at objects in Eden.

Comment: objects in eden must survive some minor collections before going to the tenured generation so you answer doesn't make sense

Comment: I think you mean young space i.e. eden and survivor spaces and collected by a minor collection.

Answer (score 0):

`WeakReference` does not prevent collection of object, so if object belongs to young space and reachable only by weak references it will be collected.

`SoftReferences` (in HotSpot JVM) act either as weak or strong references dependent on last access timestamps (timestamp of last call to `get()` on reference). 'Expiry time' of sotf reference is calculated as free memory size multiplied by coefficient configured via `-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=T` (e.g. less free memory, short expiry of soft references).

Generally, using JVM references for caching is a bad idea:
 - it promotes temporary objects to old space, breaking *weak generational hypothesis*
 - references are threat in special way by GC increasing minor GC time

If you need cache with eviction strategy it is better to implement it explicitly and account for effecting memory footprint of stored data in eviction policy.

Answer (score 0):

Some insights from Brian Goetz (article from 2006) that still seems in viguor:

[Weak References](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11225/index.html)

[Soft References](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01246/index.html) -> interesting details in the [A poor man's cache] and [How the garbage collector handles References] paragraphs.